# Should I use local storage to store user data

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, local-storage, jwt

Do I need to store the user data in the local storage after a user get authenticated. So that the next time the user won't need to login again. But it the case where I'm using a JWT authentication. Do I still need to store the user data and the token in the local storage? Because I've seen a lot of tutorial where both are stored, but I'm not able to see the utility of storing both in the local storage. Can't we verify the token when the user comes back and store the user data in the session storage?

Comment: I'm upvoting this question due to consistency of what is being asked. Alex is not asking for any ready code or something related. The question scope is about good practices in the authentication layer and treatment of user sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using JWT tokens you have to store them locally. For a REST API(probably you will use with JWT tokens) you have to send JWT tokens beside all of your requests. Because your USER API waits for a JWT token in a header or a post body. JWT tokens have information about a user to refer your user database E.g. userid, username. Do not store any user specific information in client side. A reference(userid) is enough to identify a user in your server.

If you use JWT tokens you HAVE TO store them manually-programmatically in your browser's local storage. But you can use cookies that are set by your server to make user logged in. In that case browser automatically stores your cookies and sends them with your further requests in a Cookie header.

edit: cookies are safer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I was wondering why so many tutorials stored the user data in the local storage. Then you think it's better to query the API anytime I need any user data.